# How to keep the previous foreach batch result in memory in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am receiving the events continuously from the event hub and performing the aggregation group by on 2 second window ,however the records which has 2 second window are falling into different microbatches ,how to handle this scenario in spark streaming

Input :

[image]

Following output I needed.

[image]

Here is my code

```
         group_by_attributes = ["id"] + (
             [window("timestamp", "3 seconds","2 seconds")] if agg_by_window else []
         )
       
        return (
            df.groupBy(*group_by_attributes)
            .agg(
                agg_max("col1").alias("col1"),
                agg_max("col2").alias("col2")
            )
        )
```

in my case aggregate_by_window is true

Here how to keep the previous batch data in memory and later how can i use the previous batch data in current batch or do i need to remove foreachbatch?

Comment: If your input is small you can try to use global in memory table.

Comment: my input data will continoulsy grows ,how to use global memory table

Comment: size of the batch will be 2 sec so i think the data will be less in this case

Comment: i have to group the data, but the records are falling in different micro batches

Comment: why do you want previous batch data ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I want to group by the data with 2 second window but problem here the two records are falling in one micro batch and other record is falling in another micro batch but this three records are falling in 2 second window only

Comment: Please look into input and output screenshot